# LVM linux. What does it mean LEs in my task? May be it is typo

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, lvm, xfs

at the moment I preparing to RHCSA exam and complete some tasks to achieve desired result. I have a question by this task:"Create a logical volume called linuxadm of size equal to 10 LEs in vgtest volume group (create vgtest with PE
size 32MB) with mount point /mnt/linuxadm and xfs file system structures. Create a file called linuxadmfile in the mount
point. Set the file system to automatically mount at each system reboot."

In this task I don't understand what does it mean "LEs", I tried to google this information and i found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LE means  logical extent.

From `lvcreate` man page:

> lvcreate creates a new LV in a VG. For standard LVs, this requires
> allocating **logical extents** from the VG's free
> physical extents. If there is not enough free space, the VG can be extended with  other  PVs  (vgextend(8)),  or
> existing LVs can be reduced or removed (lvremove(8), lvreduce(8).)

Comment: Ok, and what's mean "size equal 10 LEs"?

Comment: It simply means that  LV size is 10 times LE size. Here PE means physical extent. With LE size = PE size it means you need to create a 320 MB LV. See quick LVM overview: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/anatomy.html.